# Creating a search query in cloudant using node.js functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudant

How can I create a function in Node.js that could perform a query in my cloudant database and return me the matching documents which contain a particular key having a particular value in it. 
For example lets say following is by document:-

```
{
  "_id": "23966717-5A6F-E581-AF79-BB55D6BBB613",
  "_rev": "1-96daf2e7c7c0c277d0a63c49b57919bc",
  "doc_name": "Markdown Reference",
  "body": "Lorem Ipsum",
  "ts": 1422358827
}
```

and I want to search this document with its value in ts field
how can I write a function (syntax) in my app.js file which will take ts value as input and return me all the documents that contain similar ts value.

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant

Comment: Thanks Scott but I am new to Node.js and cant understand the over all flow of your projects. So it would be a great help if you could give me a little bit hint of the over all flow.

Comment: Are you using the nodejs-clodant library to interact with Cloudant, or are you using pure REST?

Comment: I am Using REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a Cloudant Query index on your database like this:

   ```
   curl -u $username:$password -X POST https://$username.cloudant.com/$databasename/_index -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"index": {"fields": ["ts"]}}'
   ```
2. make your database publicly readable
3. Here's the Node.js function:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env node
   var request = require('request');
   var ts = process.argv[2];
   if (!ts) {
     console.log('Usage: app.js <ts>');
     process.exit(1);
   }
   query(ts);

   function query(tsval) {
     var cloudantquery = {
           "selector": {
             "ts": {"$eq": parseInt(tsval)}
           },
           "fields": ["_id","doc_name"]
     };

     request({
           method: 'POST', 
           uri: 'https://$username.cloudant.com/$databasename/_find', 
           json: true, 
           body: cloudantquery
     }, function (error, response, body) {
           if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
             console.log(body);
           }
     });
   }
   ```

Comment: Here in selector can we write if else conditions? If yes how can we write.
Actually in my case i want to retrieve data some times using id and some times email so can we write conditional statement under selector.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with a similar problem so i used the official [cloudant node module](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#cloudant-query).

After installing it using 
`$ npm install --save cloudant`
,I wrote a simple module to query my cloudant database.

**cloudant.js**

```
//Query
exports.couchQuery = function(query){
    var Cloudant=require('cloudant');
  var cloudant = Cloudant({url: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', plugin:'promises'});
    var mydb = cloudant.db.use('xxxxxxxxxx');

    return mydb.find(query).then(res=>{
        return res;
    }).catch(err=>{
        return err;
    });
}
```

I used the plugin:'promises' coz i prefer to use promises over callbacks.

**routes.js**

```
app.get("/query", function (req, res) {
        couchdb.couchQuery({
            "selector": {
                "type": "input",
                "_id": {
                    "$gt": 0
                }
            },
            "fields": [
                "name",
                "quantity"
            ],
            "sort": [
                {
                    "_id": "asc"
                }
            ]
        }).then(result => {
            if (result.docs) {
                res.send(result.docs);
            }
        })
    });
```

This worked for me.

Comment: how will I sort if its a date which is stored as string.
Ex: { "name": "Alice", "datetime": "2015-11-26 10:22:24 Z" } 
For me its sorting as string when i pass in the params as
 { q:  '*:*', sort: ["-time"]}